# F# Implement list [] operator on a class?

Tags: f#, operator-overloading

I have a custom class in F# and I want to implement the [] list operator such that

```
let myClass = new myClassObj()
let someVal  = myClass.[2]
```

I can't seem to find this on the web - I probably don't know the right term to search for...  thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to implement an `Item` indexed property.  E.g.

```
type MyClass() =
  member x.Item with get(i:int) = (* some logic involving i here *)
```

Comment: many thanks - where would I go to find more somethign like this out (searching the web on [] or index or list doesn't turn up much appealing info)

Comment: @ak refer to F#'s source code. A good one is its matrix implementation in matrix.fs.

Answer (score 6):

If you start at the [F# language reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233181.aspx), and go to [members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233244.aspx), one of the topics is [indexed properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233202.aspx).

Answer (score 6):

It is worth adding that F# also supports slicing syntax (which isn't mentioned on the *indexed properites* MSDN page). It means that you can index not only a single element such as `m.[0]` but also a slice such as `m.[0..5]` or an unbounded range `m.[5..]`. This is quite useful for various numerical data types (such as matrices).

To support this feature, the type must define `GetSlice` method. The following example demonstrates this using a 2D scenario:

```
type Foo() = 
  member x.GetSlice(start1, finish1, start2, finish2) =
    let s1, f1 = defaultArg start1 0, defaultArg finish1 0
    let s2, f2 = defaultArg start2 0, defaultArg finish2 0
    sprintf "%A, %A -> %A, %A" s1 s2 f1 f2

> let f = new Foo()    
  f.[1.., 1..10];;
val it : string = "1, 1 -> 0, 10"
```

The arguments are of type `int option` and here we use `defaultArg` to specify 0 as the default value.